# Golden Week Holidays in Japan

Tags: internship, ethics, leave-of-absence, japan

Golden Week in Japan consists of 4 days i.e May 3,4,5 and 6. There is a holiday on the April 29th as well.

About a month back, my boss told me that there would be additional holidays in the company as well which he and his colleagues were deciding. At the time I thought that these are some additional holidays common to the company, so I persuaded him in order to make oncoming travel plans.

Later he informed me that these are personal holidays which he and some colleagues plan to take and are talking to their boss about the same. He advised me that I can take these holidays as well if I like. He informed me that I can take holidays on April 30th, May 1st and May 2nd. I asked him if there will be any deductions in my pay. He assured me that there won't be any deductions, so I decided that it might be a good idea to take these three holidays.

I have never taken a holiday at the company before and these are the only three I plan to take in my 6 month internship period.

Unfortunately my boss has still not confirmed to me if it would be okay to take these holidays and I feel stuck. It seems to me that there are some subtle gestures which I am missing which tell me that this is a bad decision. What should I do? When I ask him, he tells me that his boss has not yet confided in him regarding whether it's okay for him and his colleagues to take these three days off. He assures me that he will be able to confirm me once his boss has confided in him. Even if his boss says yes, should I take the holidays?

Comment: Hey Aditya, and welcome back to [workplace.se]! Why haven't you just asked your boss yet? Almost all companies in Japan have defined procedures for taking vacation, and your boss should surely know them. Why would you wait for your coworker to tell you whether he thinks it's okay for you to take vacation rather than just asking your boss? If there is a specific reason you feel you cannot ask your boss, then please [edit] your question to explain your problem more clearly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @jmac I think you misunderstood. I **did** ask my boss. Thankfully all worked out well and I had a great vacation! He was just not very sure at the time regarding if it was okay to take a holiday even though he suggested it. It seems though that extra holidays around Golden Week are quite common in Japan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just took 4 days off at my co-op. I asked in the interview process if I would get paid vacation days. You should contact HR to see whether you are entitled to any, as I know in my past co-ops I did not get any. HR will know better than your boss whether or not you are entitled to the days.

If you are, then you can wait on your boss to verify he got the days off as well. All in all, you should contact your HR rep for all the details about who you should contact for asking for time off, etc.

In the above paragraph it sounds like you should ask HR for the time off, but that's not what I meant. You should ask HR if you are entitled to days off and who to contact to request the days off and how much notice you need to get the days off.

To answer your question: Yes, you should take the days off and don't think twice about it once you've done it. From what you have stated there is truly nothing stopping you, as your manager realized you misunderstood him for thinking it was additional holidays and still told you that you can take it off. If he didn't want you to then there would have been a clear indicator, not communicated by `subtle gestures`.

If you are permitted the days off from HR, then actually taking those days should not be seen negatively by any manager as long as a manager has clear warning of the time off, its not during `peak season` and not the whole team is disappearing(most places want to keep some staff working and won't let everyone take holidays at the same time). Another factor is if you have deadlines you have to prioritize those over taking your holidays. If taking holidays means you can't meet your deadline than your boss will not be happy, and this may be were a `subtle gesture` may of appeared.

If there is any other information that I have not included, please comment.

Comment: I do have days. That's not the problem. I wonder if it's okay to take the days off.

Comment: As mentioned in the next step is to inquire about who you must inform, who must accept your holidays, how much notice you need to give etc. All of this should be information easily acquired from HR. From there, its a simple question to whomever you need to ask. I don't see why you question if its okay to take the days off, sorry if my answer didn't answer your question...

Comment: In Japan it might be considered *rude* to do something which your supervisor/boss may be against. I usually be quite careful regarding taking decisions where I feel I might be overthrowing my boss' authority. They won't say anything because they know I'm not Japanese but I would still like a good report at the end of the day. Thanks for you answer though! :D

Comment: So I worry that in case I do take the holidays, I might throw off a bad impression. And I don't want that.

Comment: Ahh, sorry. On my lunch break I will edit my answer to better reflect your question. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @AdityaSomani I have edited my post. Let me know if the answer is a better representation of what you require.

Comment: Yes, indeed this works well!